# How to make an Azure VM & configure containers to use Azure File Storage via docker CLI / quickstart terminal?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-machine

I'm using the latest Docker Toolbox and I would like to launch docker containers on Azure that connect to an Azure File Store. What should one run to achieve this from the docker quick start terminal?

Comment: I've not done this from Windows, or from docker machine, so it might not be relevant - but do you need to install the actual Azure driver? https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver

Comment: Yeah, looks like I assumed MSFT would have installed MSFT related plugins by default. There is a manual install process but doesn't provide guidance on creating getting to the box, any security considerations, prerequisites etc https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/README.md

Comment: It was basically dump the files onto the box (a conf, a binary, and a upstart) then run a script. lock the conf file down to  root only, as with any other Linux conf file. I have a salt stack script for it if its of any help

Comment: Michael - that'd be great. I'd hope that if I'm struggling others would struggle so providing an end to end sample based on the default azure docker-machine would be fantastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For more generic instructions, please use @rbj325's answer

### Create docker-machine

First things first, we need an azure VM which we can use. We can use the `docker-machine` cli to create this. This set of instructions will create it with the ubuntu 16.04LTS to simplify(ish) installation steps.

```
docker-machine create --driver azure --azure-subscription-id XXXX \
--azure-location westeurope --azure-resource-group XXX \ 
--azure-image canonical:UbuntuServer:16.04.0-LTS:latest XXXXXX
```

This sets up everything we need on Azure.

### Install azure file storage docker plugin

(Based on my knowledge of SSH) We then need to SSH into the docker-machine to be able to install the plugin.

```
docker-machine XXXXXX ssh
```

Once in, the following steps can be taken to install the plugin:

```
sudo -s
wget -qO /usr/bin/azurefile-dockervolumedriver https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver/releases/download/[VERSION]/azurefile-dockervolumedriver
chmod +x /usr/bin/azurefile-dockervolumedriver
wget -qO /etc/systemd/system/azurefile-dockervolumedriver.service https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver/master/contrib/init/systemd/azurefile-dockervolumedriver.service
cp [myconfigfile] /etc/default/
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable azurefile-dockervolumedriver
systemctl start azurefile-dockervolumedriver
systemctl status azurefile-dockervolumedriver
```

Note that there are to things required here:

1. the latest version number for the driver from github
2. a file containing some azure storage credentials

For my installation process, I made [a script](https://gist.github.com/stephlocke/a02d7b8be42604e5b6bbd19d689ab28f) that I could use and put my config file in a secure store that could be retrieved at install time. Please note it is gets the driver version 0.2.1.

Once this has completed, exit the ssh connection.

### Create volumes

You should now be able to create docker volumes

```
docker volume create --name filestore -d azurefile -o share=filestore
```

### Create docker containers

You can now use this volume with docker containers

```
docker run -it --name=example -v filestore:/filestore ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: You should update the title of the question to explicitly include "via the Quickstart terminal" as it will confuse future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create an Ubuntu VM with Docker preinstalled on Azure:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-docker-in-microsoft-azure-marketplace/

Then follow the Azure File System Docker Volume Driver install instructions here:

https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/README.md

Once you can successfully create volumes on that VM, you can make them shared volumes or Data Volume Containers to share them between your Docker containers:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/